# Generating 1000 samples at n=20 to evaluate Wald

Tags: r, simulation, exponential

I am doing a simulation study to carry out the coverage probability by generating 1000 samples at n=20 to evaluate the performance of the Wald confidence interval. I have already done the estimates the b0 and b1 but I have problems on how to generate 1000 samples.
And the confidence interval part, I can't continue since I have no samples.

```
#generate data
gen<-function(n,lambda,b0,b1){
  
  set.seed(1)
  
  u<- runif(n,0,1)
  s1<- rexp(n,lambda)
  x<- rnorm(n,0,1)
  
  t1= -log(1-sqrt(u))/(exp(-b0 - b1*x)) #inverse method
  
  s<- 1*(t1<s1)
  t= pmin(t1,s1)
  
  data1<-data.frame(x,t,t1,s1,s)
  return(data1)
}
data2<-gen(30,0.01,2,8)

x= data2$x
t= data2$t

#Likelihood
library(maxLik)
LLF<- function(para){
  set.seed(1)
  
  b0=para[1]
  b1=para[2]
  
  z1= log(2*(exp(-b0 - b1*x))) - (exp(-b0 - b1*x))*t + log(1-exp(-exp(-b0 - b1*x)*t))
  
  j=sum(z1)
  return(j)
}

mle<-maxLik(LLF,start = c(2,8))
summary(mle)
--------------------------------------------
Maximum Likelihood estimation
Newton-Raphson maximisation, 9 iterations
Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit
Log-Likelihood: -84.60377 
2  free parameters
Estimates:
     Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)    
[1,]   1.3023     0.1229   10.60  <2e-16 ***
[2,]   6.7667     0.2163   31.28  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
--------------------------------------------
```

I would be very glad if anyone have any idea or suggestion.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What samples are you looking for?

Comment: Samples for exponential parallel model for survival analysis. My pdf is f(t) = 2 * (lambda * exp(-lambda * t)) * (1- exp(-lambda * t))^2 The lambda is the covariate. lambda = exp(-b0 - b1*x) .